# Why am I getting the "Class 'Artisan' not found" error?

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently using artisan with laravel and I get the following error if I try to run any command with artisan (such as `php artisan optimize`):

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     Class
>   'Artisan' not found

I haven't seen this error anywhere on the internet and frankly am confused that it has showed up. I haven't altered any of the the core code and I have tried `composer dump-autoload` with no success. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you put the symfony tag if you use laravel ? ...

Comment: May be your php path is not correct.

Comment: I suspect it's because you don't have an `Artisan` alias, try creating one `'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,` in `app.php` inside `aliases` array

Comment: can you put logs here whats exactly error comes

Comment: @t-n-y Because the error came from symfony which is used by laravel

Comment: @morph Thank you that worked! Please add that as an answer!

Comment: @Shawn31313 glad to help, I've added it as an answer =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `config/app.php` ensure you have an alias set up like so:

```
return [
    'aliases' => [
        // ...

        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,

        // ...
    ]
];
```

Answer (score -1):

one top of the file:

```
use Artisan;
```

Comment: this doesn't do anything